# Apple Mach-O Linker Error, due to file extension

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, mach-o

The dreaded typical linker error..

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

However, it is caused by filename? I use C++/Objective-C, so all of my Obj-C files are .mm, but I can never use any .c files. For example I've included the SFMT algorithm in my project, which was giving me these errors, but just changing the single .c file to .cpp made it go away and the code works just fine! I am only including the headers, so I'm not sure why this makes any difference.

The problem now is I'm trying to include Freetype2, giving me the same issue (pretty sure it's because it's .c), but that is far too large to rename every file, and I'm also using a linked binary, so unless I recompile it with new filenames, I can't change that. So now it's time to find the real reason behind this.

Any idea why this would happen? How can I stop linker errors for .c files?

Comment: How are you generating the binary for Freetype? I'm sure you already know this, but you can't just a libfreetype.a compiled for a desktop platform.

Comment: Following this tutorial I built the binary for all 4 architectures, and combined them into the unversal freetype.a. I'm going to try again, since I get the same error running in the iOS Simulator. So it's not just that I'm missing arm6/7.

Comment: You forgot to post the link to the tutorial. I use the method described here (http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) when using 3rd-party libs. The only problem I get with this method is that when I change something in a library, the app is not relinked with the updated library unless I do Clean first.

Comment: Whoops.. sorry about that. This is the link: http://librocket.com/wiki/documentation/BuildingFreeTypeForiOS

Comment: There's also a prebuilt version, linked to on that page, I tried using that instead of the one I compiled (I used their include/ dir as well), but I'm still getting linker errors. I've tried Cleaning as well. I've also found that setting Build Active Architecture Only to YES reduces errors, but still says "file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice for architecture armv7." I'm wary of

Comment: Got it all working, my last step was that I needed to link to the zlib framework, I wasn't aware Freetype required this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Freetype includes within an `extern "C"` directive:

```
// Non-C includes
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    #include <freetype/freetype.h>
    // ... Other freetype includes
}
```

You can probably use `#import` instead of `#include` within an `extern "C"` directive. I've never tried, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Good to know. This solved my properly problem with SFMT, but Freetype is still complaining, so there's probably something wrong with the binary or linkage, I'll have to look into it more. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Surround your c header file with this.  This can also surround the include:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus   
extern "C" {         
#endif     

// function declarations etc if this is your own header.
// OR you can use this in the .mm file to surround your include.
//...

#ifdef __cplusplus       
};                       
#endif
```

This specifies external linkage for your c functions.
If you don't do this when you include your c .h files the C++ compiler will mangle in a different way from the C compiler, and cause problems for the linker.
By using `extern "C"`, you are telling your C++ compiler to use C-style mangling of the functions.

Comment: This would have to be done for each Freetype header the OP wants to include. Modifying 3rd party libraries leads to maintenance headaches when those libraries are later updated.

Comment: Good point - I first missed that the OP was including a 3rd party lib.  If it's his own code he may prefer to use the linkage specification in the header (So he doesn't have to do it at every include).  I modified my answer to include your suggestion.